# Put data into alternating table columns

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I've been working on an ASP.net MVC project and currently I am pulling data from a database and displaying them in alternating rows. So the display of data will be as follows.

---

### | 1st | 2nd |

### | 3rd | 4th |

And so on. I have managed to do this correctly with the following code. To me this seems pretty inefficient and I am asking is if there is a much simpler way to do this. Thanks.

```
@{
@:<table>

int modcheck = 0;

foreach (var item in @Model)
{
    if(modcheck % 2 == 0 )
    {
        @:<tr><td style="width:400px">
        <h3>@item.Name</h3>
        @:</td>
    }

    else
    {

        @:<td style="width:400px">
        <h3>@item.Name</h3>
        @:</td></tr>
    }

    modcheck++;
}

@:</table>

}
```

Comment: Honestly looks fine to me. If you're styling with tables rather than displaying tabular data you might rather use CSS to lay out what you want but... yeah. Looks fine.

Comment: For efficiency type questions, http://codereview.stackexchange.com might be a better site...

Comment: @cullub thanks. I'll note that for future reference

Comment: @cullub Maybe, but the constant comment on nearly every question these days "Oh, that would be a better question for Code Review" is annoying.

Comment: @jdphenix You're right.  It seems that people don't really know the definition of that site...  Really though, This is the exact kind of question their site was created for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing a foreach loop you could do a for loop and increment by two, something like:

```
for (int x=0; x < @Model.Lenght; x += 2)
{
    @:<tr>
    @:<td style="width: 400px"><h3>@Model[x]</h3></td>
    @:<td style="width: 400px"><h3>@Model[x+1]</h3></td>
    @:</tr>
}
```

My ASP is a little rusty and this probably wont compile, but it should get you going.

Comment: I like this one, just remember to consider odd numbers of things - `@Model[x+1]` will throw an exception in that case.